# Pyautogui: How to type alt codes?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've been trying to type an '@' with pyautogui. This can be done with alt + 64 on my keyboard. But for some reason it doesn't type any @. Also it seems u can't type any other symbols with alt codes.

```
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','6', '4')
```

I've tried alot of different but no solution ;/

Comment: It's likely that `pyautogui.hotkey` is running too fast to be registered by the underlying systems. Perhaps try doing a `.keyDown` on each key, a `time.sleep` in the middle, and a `.keyUp` after

Comment: @ritlew, I've already tried alot of combinations like you said but really nothing works. It's also pretty annoying to test these things out because I keep accidently changing the settings of my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the hold() function in pyautogui to hold down a key while other keys press.
for an example, `with pyautogui.hold('alt'): pyautogui.press(['6','4'])`
Just make sure to make a new line and indent the pyautogui.press
I hope I could help!